# Can my laptop have its own resource record (DNS Database)?

Tags: database, networking, dns, server, client

I was studying DNS and I am confused about resource record topic. Can my laptop has its own resource record if yes how can I see that?
Or does local DNS server of my ISP carry the resource records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Resource records" are fairly basic data containers in DNS. They have types, like A for IPv4 addresses, AAAA for IPv6 addresses, MX for mail server hostnames and so on. Nearly all of the time, they live in a larger container, such as a zone file, a query packet or a response packet. *Everything* in DNS basically comes down to sending resource records around. They are kind of the molecules of DNS; made from more basic parts but still the building blocks of everything interesting.

The question "Can my laptop have its own resource record" makes no sense, so it cannot be answered. There can certainly be many resource records that hold information about your laptop. Your laptop can certainly send and receive resource records, either in the form of query and response packets or by running a name server.